# Halacha of moons disappearance during kiddish levanah?

Tags: halacha, blessing, kiddush-levanah, moon

I thought I’ve read somewhere the moon needs to be visible (although you don’t look up at it) the entirety of kiddish levanah, so when it’s completed and you look up, the moon is still visible. Does anyone know if this is true or the text support for it?

For example, if someone was to start kiddish levanah with a visible moon, and when completing, looks up to see no moon. How is one certain the moon was visible during the bracha, or what if it disappeared right before the end of the first bracha? Does he need to repeat it?

Comment: Relevant: https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.97.7?with=all&lang=bi